# Trim the length of the productname

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, salesforcedx

I´m showing products automatically by typing in an product ID.
But there´s a small challenge left with the productname.

The DE-field may have 1000 characters, but I want to show only 40 charcaters and set a "..." only when it is longer than that.

[image]

current code:

```
    /* TRIM Produktname */
set @ln = length(@P_I_Title_a)
set @cutoffPos = length(@P_I_Title_a)
set @done = 0

if @ln > @maxLen then
    for @l = @maxLen downto 1 do
      if substring(@P_I_Title_a,@l,1) == " " or substring(@P_I_Title_a,@l,1) == "-" and @done == 0 then
         set @cutoffPos = subtract(@l,1)
         set @done = 1
      endif
    next @l      
endif
set @P_I_Title_a = CONCAT(substring(@P_I_Title_a,1,@cutoffPos)," ... ")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following method to accomplish the same thing in a template recently. It uses the [IIF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/iif.htm), [Length](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Length.htm), [Concat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm), and [Substring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Substring.htm) functions and it worked pretty well.

```
%%=IIF(Length(@P_I_Title_a) > 40,concat(Substring(@P_I_Title_a,1,40), '...'),@P_I_Title_a)=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the `@maxLen` anywhere?

```
%%[

    var @productName, @l, @ln, @cutoffPos, @done, @productNameTrimmed

    set @productName = AttributeValue("productName")
    set @ln = length(@productName)
    set @cutoffPos = length(@productName)
    set @done = 0
    set @maxLen = 40

    if @ln > @maxLen then

        for @l = @maxLen downto 1 do

          if substring(@productName,@l,1) == " " and @done == 0 then

             set @cutoffPos = subtract(@l,1)
             set @done = 1

          endif

        next @l

    endif

    set @productNameTrimmed = concat(replacelist(substring(@productName,1,@cutoffPos),"",",","-"),"...")

]%%
%%=v(@productNameTrimmed)=%%
```